# ORACLE NUMBER(*,0) equivalent in POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle, database-migration, sqldatatypes

I have a table in ORACLE with a column which has a data type of `NUMBER(*,0)`. As per my understanding it means precision will be 38 since that is the maximum limit of precision and scale value will be 0 which means no numbers will be allowed after decimal point i.e. will store integers?

I have a requirement where I have to create same table in PostgreSQL. Is it possible to write `NUMERIC(*,0)` in PostgreSQL? If not, what will be PostgreSQL equivalent of `NUMBER(*,0`)?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: I would use numeric with no precision

Comment: If i just write NUMERIC wont it create with any precision and scale? I want a scale of 0 @Philippe

Comment: You should investigate what you are storing in that column. Maybe a `bigint` in Postgres is enough?

Answer (score 1):

**in oracle numeric (precision,scale)**

```
number(precision,scale)
numeric (precision,scale)
```

*precision = If a precision is not specified, the column stores values as given*

*scale = If no scale is specified, the scale is zero*

[oracle number](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832)

**in sql,postgresql**

```
numeric(precision,scale)
```

*precision = With a maximum length of 38 and With default value 18 in sql*

Answer (score 1):

Postgres supports arbitrary precision numeric values.  The Oracle `number` type has up to 38 digits of precision.  So, the type:

```
number(*, 0)
```

is really:

```
number(38, 0)
```

The equivalent in Postgres is:

```
numeric(38)
```

or:

```
numeric(38, 0)
```

However, [Postgres supports ridiculously large precisions and scales](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL).  So if you specify:
numeric

You will be able to represent any number that you are likely to encounter or need in your lifetime.